# How to correctly transfer the value from html to js? html, node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I get the value from an html page, and I want to color the cell in js relative to the received value

For example, ID = 11, hence the 11 cell of the table is decorated

I write in ID 11, but cell 11 is not decorated

```js
function Complete() {
  if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
    let fm = document.sell.values.value
    let element = document.getElementById(fm)
    element.style.background = 'black'
  }
}
Complete()
```

```html
<form name="sell">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>ID: </b></td>
      <td><input name="values" SIZE=2 0 onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input TYPE="button" value="Готово" onClick="Complete;">
</form>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td id="11">11</td>
    <td id="12">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please elaborate, where is the example code run? On a client or on your server?

Comment: Run on the client

Comment: 1. Add a value to the field before calling Complete(). 2. add `()` to the Complete in the onclick

Comment: need some detail about running the code